# Рассчитать значения функции f(x) в целочисленном интервале Python

Tags: python

> Дана функция, вычисляющая значение переменной *`y`* в зависимости от
>   переменной *`x`*. Дан интервал целых чисел, которые может принимать
>   переменная *x*.
>
> Необходимо написать программу на языке Python, которая
>   выведет в текстовый файл `result.txt` значения переменной *y* для
>   каждого из предложенных *`x`*.
>
> Точность значений `*у*` при распечатке
>   установить в 3 знака после запятой.
>   Кодировка в текстовом файле должна
>   быть Unicode. 
>   Путь к входному и выходному файлу в коде программы нужно
>   сделать относительным.

Сваял вот такое:

```
import math
import cmath
f = open('source_data.txt')
a = f.readlines()
for i in a:
x = float(i.strip('x='))

if x < -6:
    n = ((64 * x ** 7 - 44 * x ** 2 + 44) ** 5 + 56 * x ** 7) / (
            (15 * x ** 7 + x ** 3) ** 3 + (34 * x ** 2 + 15) ** 4)
    f1 = open("result.txt", 'a')
    f1.write("При x = " + str(x) + " значение y = " + str(n) + "\n")

elif -6 <= 0 and x < 0:

    n = (math.sqrt(((65 * x ** 4 + 47 * x ** 2 + 14) ** 5)) - 66 * x ** 3) / (
            (9 * x ** 6 + x ** 2) ** 5 + (71 * x ** 2 - 57) ** 5)
    print(n)
else:
    n = ((46 * x ** 7 + 39 * x ** 2 + 16) ** 8 - 91 * x ** 5) / ((27 * x ** 8 - x ** 3) ** 3 + cmath.sqrt(((8 * x - 65) ** 3)))
    print(n)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Интересует правильность ввода формул, как сделать точность до 3 знаков после запятой, и конечно же ошибки которые есть в коде.

Comment: Точность 3 знака после запятой  a = float('{:.3f}'.format(x))

Comment: @Стас, если нужна точность при печати, то не нужно обратно в float преобразовывать.

Comment: А почему бы не запустить код и не посмотреть на ошибки самому. Вы же почему-то предлаагете нам  подработать интерпретатором.  Ну а про "правильность ввода формул" - совсем загадочная просьба. Кстати, у вас в коде "вывода в текстовый файл" я не вижу.

Comment: Код работает как мне надо, но вычисления выдают заоблачные цифры, в связи с этим и прошу помощи. И может кто то сможет предложить более удобные варианты записи. И код не дописан до конца, только основной функционал который я проверяю

Comment: "Код работает как мне надо, но вычисления выдают заоблачные цифры." Приведите пример. Кстати -12 в 35-степени, это таки да, "заоблачно" Про 5 в 56 степени(!!!!!!) я даже не говорю.

Comment: Вот один результат, 
При x = -12.0 значение y = 4.084748354907904e+20

Comment: Ну, так 12 в 35 степени это 59066822915424320448445358917464096768. Что вас смущает?

Comment: то что при выставлении точности цифра меняется и округляется, т.е после точки стоят нули

Comment: Особенности работы с плавающей точкой. Работайте с фиксированной, тем более что новые версии Python позволяют работать с int числами практически произвольной длины. К float переходите только при делении.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то сначала я использую int, а в формулах привожу к float делимое и делитель и только потом вывожу с точностью результат ?

Comment: Ну, как-то примерно так. Возможно - еще перед взятием корней.

Comment: Спасибо passant, без сторонней помощи тяжело разбираться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После длительных "переговоров" вырисовывается следующее.

Если исходить из ДОСЛОВНОЙ трактовки вопроса, а именно - "как сделать точность **до 3 знаков после запятой**" оказывается, что просто написать, например

```
n = ((64 * x ** 7 - 44 * x ** 2 + 44) ** 5 + 56 * x ** 7) / (
                    (15 * x ** 7 + x ** 3) ** 3 + (34 * x ** 2 + 15) ** 4)
```

некорректно, потому что получаемый ответ, опять же например, при x = -10.0  дает значение y= 3.182e+19, а это НИКАК не 3 знака после запятой.

Что-бы получить именно знаки после запятой - можно написать так:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x=10
a=(64 * x ** 7 - 44 * x ** 2 + 44) ** 5 + 56 * x ** 7
b=((15 * x ** 7 + x ** 3) ** 3 + (34 * x ** 2 + 15) ** 4)
format(Decimal.from_float(a)/Decimal.from_float(b),'.3f')
```

Результат

```
'31812853625432199804.219'
```

Что в точности соответствует поставленному условию.

Answer (score 0):

Какие-то правки:

```
import math
import cmath


with open('source_data.txt') as f, open("result.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f1:
    for i in f:
        x = float(i.strip('x='))

        if x < -6:
            n = ((64 * x ** 7 - 44 * x ** 2 + 44) ** 5 + 56 * x ** 7) / (
                    (15 * x ** 7 + x ** 3) ** 3 + (34 * x ** 2 + 15) ** 4)

        elif -6 <= x < 0:
            n = (math.sqrt(((65 * x ** 4 + 47 * x ** 2 + 14) ** 5)) - 66 * x ** 3) / (
                    (9 * x ** 6 + x ** 2) ** 5 + (71 * x ** 2 - 57) ** 5)
            print(n)
        else:
            n = ((46 * x ** 7 + 39 * x ** 2 + 16) ** 8 - 91 * x ** 5) / ((27 * x ** 8 - x ** 3) ** 3 + cmath.sqrt(((8 * x - 65) ** 3)))
        f1.write("При x = {} значение y = {:.3e}\n".format(x, n))
        print("{:.3e}".format(n))
```

---

1. Я не поверял ваши вычисления.
2. Я исправил ошибки в отступах.
3. Я исправил ошибку в команде `elif -6 <= 0 and x < 0:`
4. `open("result.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")` (вместо вашего `open("result.txt", 'a')`)
5. Точность значений *у* при распечатке установил в 3 знака после запятой.
6. ... и что-то другое...

Я проверил этот код — вот мой выводной файл `result.txt`:

> ```
> При x = 7.0 значение y = 1.125e+36-8.058e+12j
> При x = -4.0 значение y = 5.859e-13
> При x = -10.0 значение y = 3.182e+19
> При x = 0.0 значение y = 0.000e+00-8.196e+06j
> ```

Comment: Благодарю, надеюсь что этого хватит для оценки и буду продолжать изучать программирование.

Comment: Увы, приведенные результаты не удовлетворяют условию "три знака ПОСЛЕ ЗАПЯТОЙ".